# error "invalid filename" if i use letters a to f in file name

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-handling

i'm using pyton 2.7. I have written a script , when it is executed, it will call and run some other file with the name abc.py. but i'm getting error

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('r') or filename: 'F:\x07bc.c'
```

it is working fine if i change the file name. 
it shows error only if i use letters from a to f as the first letter of file name
Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
open(r'F:\abc.c')
```

i.e. add `r` before quotes.

**UPDATE** Sorry, I misinterpreted the code (although my solution is correct). @DavidHeffernan is right, the `\a` is read as the ASCII bell.

Comment: The first sentence of the answer is simply incorrect. The literal `\a` is the ASCII bell. There is no hexadecimal interpretation here. It's true that Python uses hexadecimal to display the ASCII bell, that's the `\x07`, but that's not what you said.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the Python string `'\a'`. As described in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), the back slash character is interpreted as an escape character. So `'\a'` is in fact the ASCII Bell character, character number 7.

Your filename is `'F:\abc.c'` and the `\a` in there is interpreted as ASCII Bell. You can see this clearly in the interpretor:

```
>>> 'F:\abc.c'
'F:\x07bc.c'
>>> print 'F:\abc.c'
F:bc.c
```

When you print that string note that the `\a` does not appear. That's because it has been turned into a Bell control character which is invisible.

To include a backslash you can use the correct escape sequence `\\`. Put it all together and your filename should be: `'F:\\abc.c'`. As an alternative, you can prefix the string with `r` to make it a raw string. This is also detailed in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

```
>>> 'F:\\abc.c'
'F:\\abc.c'
>>> print 'F:\\abc.c'
F:\abc.c
>>> r'F:\abc.c'
'F:\\abc.c'
>>> print r'F:\abc.c'
F:\abc.c
```

Comment: This should be accepted +1 and excellent explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the `\` with another backslash, like this:

```
print 'F:\\x07bc.c'
```